# Persist authentication Laravel on iOS Devices

Tags: ios, laravel, react-native, webview

I'm currently building an app that basically wraps my Laravel webapp inside the react native web-view.
The problem I'm currently facing is the iOS doesn't seem to persist authentication at all.
Android seem to work fine even after I close the app and open it again but I've to log into the web-view every-time I open an app.
What would be the solution here?

I do have a solution which is basically storing the some auth information after user logs in and store that in the AsyncStorage of React Native but I just am not able to find what exactly to push to asyncStorage. The app_session and csrf_token obviously doesn't help to authenticate user otherwise i could have just passed those when user opens app on iOS but it doesn't help in authenticating user in anyway.

Basically, I want to pull some value when user login in and send that to asyncStorage and when user reopens app in iOS, I want to pass that as cookie and make Laravel feel like it is an authenticated user.
But I just don't seem to find what exactly should I pass to server via AsyncStorage.

Any help?

P.S. I'm not looking for any API authentication, just want a solution from existing web app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to solve it by passing encrypted id and password stored in AsyncStorage and create middleware on backend if any valid auth has been passed.